# Increasing weights of TF IDF matrix terms

Tags: cluster-analysis, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I have tf idf matrix for documents. I have some terms whose weights I want to double up in TFIDF matrix. say I have matrix weightTerms and I have following code

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=1,stop_words="english")
term_freq_matrix = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(vectoriser.mydoclist)
# print "Vocabulary:", count_vectorizer.vocabulary_

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer


tfidf = TfidfTransformer(norm="l2")
tfidf.fit(term_freq_matrix)

tf_idf_matrix = tfidf.transform(term_freq_matrix)
print len(count_vectorizer.get_feature_names())
for term in count_vectorizer.get_feature_names(): 
    # [k for k in count_vectorizer.get_feature_names() if '#' in k]:
    # if '#' in term:
    print term.encode('utf-8')# print np.matrix(tf_idf_matrix.todense())
# np.savetxt("foo.csv", (np.matrix(tf_idf_matrix.todense())), delimiter=",")
# np.savetxt("foo.csv", tf_idf_matrix.toarray(),fmt="%.4e")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't necessarily do that, and it's not recommended even if you find a way/hack to do it. One hack would be to ensemble multiple models, weighted - with one feature per model. This is not a tested approach, so proceed with caution.

Do Recursive Feature Elimination (RFE) to see how it affects your accuracy + precision + recall. Also, rank your features using random forests benchmarks to be able to see which feature gives your model more variance.